# Disable/enable Windows magnifier for specific applications

Tags: magnifier

I need to use Windows Magnifier with inverted color most of the time. However, there are specific applications in which I prefer to use the application's high contrast settings (Chrome's high contrast extension, Visual Studio's dark theme). Is there any way to disable Magnifier when the active window is one of these applications?

As a second option, is it possible to automatically close Magnifier when one of these applications is in the foreground? I can open Magnifier with a keyboard shortcut.

Comment: What you want should be possible with a custom AutoHotkey script.